# Uploading a file with google cloud API with a PUT at root of server?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a server using the google Drive API. I tried with a curl PUT request to upload a simple file (test.txt) at http://myserver/test.txt. As you can see, I did the PUT request at the root of my server. The response I get is the following:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UqANa4Bj6ilL7z5HZH0wlQi_ufxDiHPtb2zq1Gzcx7IxAEcOt-AOlWsbX1q_lsZUwWt_hyKOA3weAeVpQvPQTwbQhLhIA
ETag: "6e809cbda0732ac4845916a59016f954"
x-goog-generation: 1548877817413782
x-goog-metageneration: 1
x-goog-hash: crc32c=jwfJwA==
x-goog-hash: md5=boCcvaBzKsSEWRalkBb5VA==
x-goog-stored-content-length: 6
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 19:50:17 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-bwi5139-BWI, cache-cdg20732-CDG
X-Cache: MISS, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
X-Timer: S1548877817.232336,VS0,VE241
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,PUT,PATCH,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control,X-Requested-With,Authorization,Content-Type,Location,Range
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 300`

I know you're not supposed to use the API that way. I did that for testing purposes. I understand every headers returned but can't figure out if my file has been uploaded because I don't have enough knowledge of this API.
My question is very simple :
Just by looking at the response, can you tell me if my file has been uploaded ?
If yes can I retrieve it and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP status code traditionally indicates, for any given request, if it was successful.  The status code in the response is always on the first line:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

200 type status codes mean success.  You should take some time to familiarize yourself with [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) if you intend to work with HTTP APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is a good news. But is there a way with the information above to retrieve the path to the file ? (cause an upload service that says upload successful without providing a way to retrieve the file seems kind of strange)

Comment: You specified the path when you performed the PUT, didn't you?  That's everything after "myserver".

Comment: No, its not working, got a 404 error message when I try to access my file. I think google cloud storage API doesn't work that way. It generates an id or something to access the uploaded file. But because I didn't use it the normal way I can't retrieve the path to the file.

Comment: Well, the documentation would tell you how it works, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mtoypc - Google Drive and Google Cloud Storage are different services. Read the documentation and study the many examples of REST APIs. The API is very easy to use once you understand the basics of HTTP requests and the Google API style.